# largest number. Given a list of non negative integers, arrange them such that they form the largest number

Tags: c++

Why is this code giving the wrong output?

**Question**: Given a list of non negative integers, arrange them such that they form the largest number.

For example:

Given [3, 30, 34, 5, 9], the largest formed number is 9534330.

Note: The result may be very large, so you need to return a string instead of an integer.

This is my code:

```
bool compareinterval(int x,int y);
string Solution::largestNumber(const vector<int> &A) 
{
    //sort(A.begin(),A.end());
    vector< int>B;
    int i,x=0;
    for(i=0;i<A.size();i++)
       B.push_back(A[i]);
    sort(B.begin(),B.end(),compareinterval);
    vector<string> vect;

string result;

    for(i=0;i<B.size();i++)
    {

      ostringstream convert;
    convert<<B[i];
    if(B[i]!=0)
       x=1;

    string str1=convert.str();
        result.append(str1);
    }
   if(x==0)
      return "0";
    else
     return result;

}
bool compareinterval(int x,int y)
{
    ostringstream convert;
    string result;
    convert<<x;
    string str1=convert.str();
     //ostringstream convert;
    //string result;
   // ostringstream convert;
    convert<<y;
    string str2=convert.str();
    int i;




    for(i=0;i<min(str1.length(),str2.length());i++)
    {
        if((str1[i]-'0')<(str2[i]-'0'))  
           return false;
         if((str1[i]-'0')>(str2[i]-'0'))  
           return true;


    }
    //return true;
    if(str1.length()<str2.length())
       return true;
else
    return false;



}
```

This is the input and output:

```
input:A : [ 9, 99, 999, 9999, 9998 ]
my output:999899999999
```

I have defined compare function which is not working  properly .

Can someone correct it?

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `convert<<x; convert<<y;` have you verified this works the way you need it to work?

Comment: The algorithm given by @Superman is undoubtedly a more preferable one and should help you, but your question is why doesn't your code work. In other words, "please debug my code for me", and that is generally considered off-topic for SO.

Comment: @goyalsaransh002 ! I think example on post is not correct. `[3, 30, 34, 5, 9]` -> `9534330` is it right? `9534303` isn't it?

Comment: @Alexander 9534330 is obviously larger than 9534303.

Comment: @goyalsaransh002, Could you please post your full source code.? I've a idea that can help you, but I need your environment and full source code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what comes to mind.

1. Convert all input to string - 10 to "10"
2. Use `std::sort` to arrange strings in descending order. You could use a custom compare method or `strcmp` perhaps.
3. Now simply concatenate the rearranged strings.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that:

```
    convert<<x;
    string str1=convert.str();

    convert<<y;
    string str2=convert.str();
```

you are appending second integer to first integer. For example, if x is 9, y is 8, str1 will be 9 and str2 will be 98. That is NOT what you wanted. 
Instead use separate variables (or reset stringstream before reusing)

```
    convert1<<x;
    string str1=convert1.str();

    convert2<<y;
    string str2=convert2.str();
```

This should make things work.